# Swift how to animate up the screen while staying centered, but also shrink in size

Tags: swift, swift2

I want to do a simple animation where the logo moves from point A on the screen at size 1 to point B on the screen at size 2

I found

```
self.logoOutlet.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 115, height: 115)
```

how do i get it so the x is centered no matter what size the phone is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have to do math, to calculate the value of `x` based on the bounds of the `superview` of `logoOutlet` or use AutoLayout and just use a center X constraint (which is probably the better choice).

You can read about the specifics in the documentation: [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/), or use one of the many tutorials on Auto Layout you can find via Google search.

Answer (score 0):

Through a combination of two different answers I found a solution that works

```
self.logoOutlet.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.midX, y: 26, width: 115, height: 115)
self.logoOutlet.center.x = self.view.center.x
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using Auto Layout:

```
@IBAction func animateLogo(sender: UIButton) {
    let newView = UIView()
    newView.backgroundColor = .redColor()
    newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.view.addSubview(newView)

    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 500.0)

    let centerXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)

    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 200)

    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 200)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([topConstraint, centerXConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    // Now change the constraint for the second point
    widthConstraint.constant = 50
    heightConstraint.constant = 50
    topConstraint.constant = 50

    // Animate the move over 5 seconds
    UIView.animateWithDuration(5.0) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

---

[image: demo running in iOS simulator]